Avoid LEFT JOIN and use a subquery instead
I know that using a left join is much more efficient than using subqueries, but I'm having a problem using left join with my database, that's why I would like to test the query using a subquery, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to do it.
The query is as follows:
SELECT
    o.hash,
    o.index,
    o."timestamp" AS created_timestamp,
    i."timestamp" AS spent_timestamp,
    i.number AS spent_number,
    o.number AS created_number,   
    o.value,
    (SELECT usd FROM blocks b WHERE b.number = o.number),
    (SELECT usd FROM blocks b WHERE b.number = i.number)
  FROM 
    o
  LEFT JOIN 
    i
  ON o.hash = i.spent_hash 
  AND o.index = i.spent_index

I would like to build it using a subquery.

Could you add some simple data and the expected output as text ?  and what problem you have using left join ?

but I'm having a problem using left join with my database What kind of problem? And why you use LEFT join - do you need in it really? does INNER is not enough?

Note a syntax error,  an extra comma at the end of the select list.

"I know that using a left join is much more efficient than using subqueries" that's a complete myth. Sometimes they are faster, sometimes slower, depends on query plan, statistics etc.

Without a query plan you hardly know anything about efficiency. Please share the plan and the ddl for all tables and indexes involved

try:
SELECT
    o.hash,
    o.index,
    o."timestamp" AS created_timestamp,
    (SELECT i."timestamp" 
     FROM i 
     WHERE i.spent_hash = o.hash AND i.spent_index = o.index) AS spent_timestamp,
    (SELECT i.number 
     FROM i 
     WHERE i.spent_hash = o.hash AND i.spent_index = o.index) AS spent_number,
    o.number AS created_number,   
    o.value,
    (SELECT b.usd 
     FROM blocks b 
     WHERE b.number = o.number) AS created_usd,
    (SELECT b.usd 
     FROM blocks b 
     WHERE b.number = (SELECT i.number 
                       FROM i 
                       WHERE i.spent_hash = o.hash AND i.spent_index = o.index)) AS spent_usd_corrected
FROM 
    o


This part isn't correct, the rest works
(SELECT b.usd FROM blocks b WHERE b.number = (SELECT i.number FROM i WHERE i.spent_hash = o.hash AND i.spent_index = o.index)) AS spent_usd
